# How to display the labels inside frames, not instead of them

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a my first GUI and am confused about how frames work. How do I place a label inside a frame?

```py
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("RPG")
        self.window.geometry("600x400")
        self.window.configure(bg="black")
        self.window.grid_anchor(anchor=CENTER)

        self.header = Frame(self.window, bg="green", height=25, width=600)
        self.frame = Frame(self.window, bg="red", height=375, width=600)

        self.header.grid(row=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=1)

        self.label1 = Label(self.header, text="Hello World", bg="black", fg="white")
        self.label2 = Label(self.frame, text="This is the Game")

        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=0)


root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I would like to display both frames, just as color-blocks for now, and have a centered label in each, but it doesn't display the frames at all, just the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, frames (and all other widgets) will shrink or expand to fit their contents. So, when you put the labels inside the frames, the frames shrink to fit the label.

Also, you're using `grid`, and `grid` will create the smallest possible rows and columns to fit what is in the row and column. `grid` only uses as much space as necessary, and won't make use of extra space unless you've configured it to do so. Not only that, but grid will center items in the space allocated, so even if the column or row is larger than the item, the item won't fill that row or column.

While it may seem counter-intuitive at first, these rules actually work quite well once you understand how `grid` works.

Assuming that you want `header` and `frame` to fill the window, you need to configure `grid` to know what to do with extra available space. This is done by giving the row or column a "weight".

For example, assuming you want `self.header` to be a horizontal stip across the top, and `self.frame` to take up all of the extra space, you need to add the following statement:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

With row zero having the default weight of 0 (zero), `grid` will give all extra vertical space to `self.frame`. By setting a weight of 1 (one) to column zero, that column will get all extra horizontal space.

With that, the frame will be allocated just enough space at the top for the header, and all of the extra space will be allocated to `self.frame`. There's one more step that needs to be done.

Even though `self.frame` has been given all of the extra space, you need to tell `grid` to stretch the frame to fit all of it's allocated space. You do this with the `sticky` option. It takes letters representing points on a compass: n (north), s (south), e (east), and w (west). To have the frame fill all of it's allocated space you want it to "stick" to all four sides:

```
self.frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Similarly, to get the header to stretch to fill all the way across horizontally, you can tell it to "stick" to the east and west:

```
self.header.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew")
```

With that, the green header frame will fill the top part of the screen, and the red frame will fill all of the rest of the space.

[image: screenshot]

This is probably still not exactly what you want, but the problem is identical. If you want the label to be allocated all of the space in the header you need to use give row and column 0 a weight. Doing that will center the label. If you want the label to fill the space allowed, use `sticky`.

Likewise, if you want all of the other label to fill the bottom frame, give that row and column a weight and the label will be centered in the space. If you want it to fill all of the allocated space, use `sticky`.

For example:

```
    self.header.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.header.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hey, I've been going over it so many times, and have figured out the "weight" myself, and had read about "sticky" but had understood it wrongly. You explained my question wonderfully! Couldn't be more greatful :) thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

The default borderwidth of a `Frame` is `0` which mean no border. If you want one, then specify a value greater the zero. For example — note the added `bd=1` keyword arguments (you can also use `borderwidth=1`):

In addition, if you want the text centered in the labels, you have to give them a minimum `width` (number of characters) *and* specify how you want the text to aligned within that space via an `anchor` option.

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title("RPG")
        self.window.geometry("600x400")
        self.window.configure(bg="black")
        self.window.grid_anchor(anchor="center")

        self.header = tk.Frame(self.window, bg="green", height=25, width=600, bd=1)
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.window, bg="red", height=375, width=600, bd=1)

        self.header.grid(row=0)
        self.frame.grid(row=1)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self.header, text="Hello World", bg="black", fg="white",
                      width=15, anchor='center')  # ADDED
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="This is the Game",
                      width=15, anchor='center')  # ADDED

        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label2.grid(row=0, column=0)


root = tk.Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:
[image: Screenshot showing result]

Comment: thanks, but I would like to have the background color displayed too, which isn't getting displayed. I don't understand why....